# Application crashing when locale is changed

Tags: android, locale

My application is currently running with chinese locale.Whenever i try to set the locale , while the application is running, it crashes.
I start my app>> long press on home button  and select settings to change the locale>> after changing i simply press back key to see my app but it crashes.
Actually my app gets data from a server and display it whenever started..I have cheked in the logcat ,that when i press back after setting locale , my app hits the server to fetch data but server somehow does not respond therefore resulting in crash.
What could be he issue?

Also my app always show ServiceConnection Leaked statement in logcat when back key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a locale `string/drawable` that's not there in the default set.

Read why default resources are important.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html